# Qt SDK 1.2.1 on flash drive

Tags: c++, qt, ide, installation, usb-flash-drive

Would anyone know how one may go about installing Qt SDK 1.2.1 package on a flash drive for plug and play anywhere?  If I wanted to do it for Windows would I simply install it from the installer package?  Is this even possible?

**Update:**

Answered below for three OS's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Windows**

You may install Qt SDK 1.2.1 to run on the assigned drive letter of the flash USB at the time of installation.

However, to answer the question there is no way to set the Qt Creator settings to dynamically change drive destination resources for plug and play.  If you wish to load Qt Creator on a foreign system the USB drive must be assigned the drive letter assigned at its installation.

**Unix / Linux**

UNIX and Linux systems reportedly have methods of achieving dynamic drive path assignments for USB applications.

**Mac**

Unknown. Stay tuned or supply a answer please.

I do remember reading the macs had their own mini OS just for applications to run solely on flash drives. I want to confirm before I say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Qt SDK on the flash drive device ? Yes.

Comment: I believe you are correct, there is more to figure out on how to do it though.  To note, your answer lacks depth can you add to it.  If not I would remove it as a "Answer" and place in comments so you don't get anymore down marks.  I added a point to hopefully counter who ever down voted your answer.

Comment: When you install the Qt SDK, the system asks you in which folder you want to install the SDK (generally a folder named "`QtSDK`"). All the SDK files will be in this folder. So in your case, you can tell the system that you want to put this "`QtSDK`" folder (with all its content `;-)`) on the flash drive device. Sorry for the lack of precision.